# Asp.Net core Razor Taghelpers - mandatory parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

If I create an EmailTagHelper like this:

```
public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "a";
        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("href", "mailto:" + this.EmailAddress);
        output.Content.SetContent(this.Content);
    }
}
```

I can use it like this:

```
<email content="Mail me!" email-address="hello@world.com"></email>
```

However, I can also do this without getting an error in Visual Studio or a compile error:

```
<email content="Mail me - but where!?"></email>
```

Is there a way to mark properties mandatory, so that they can trigger compile errors or at least a red squiggle in Visual Studio, so the error does not occur at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the required attribute name to the `HtmlTargetElement`:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("email", Attributes ="email-address")]
public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This solution will not trigger compiler errors or show a warning message, but at least the html tag will not be rendered in **bold green** in the editor till you provide the required attributes.

If you want to throw an exception when the attribute is not provided, it must be removed from the `HtmlTargetElement` attributes:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("email")]
public class EmailTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EmailAddress))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(EmailAddress));

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The second option is much better, that way the developer using your tag will get an exception letting him know he missed something. I'd add a description to the exception to let him know what is happening.